# Maximo Anywhere, issue in Clearing lookup value in particular scenario

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am working in the Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 (WorkExecution app)
In the Create follow up work order, I have added the new lookup as a required attribute to the create followup. Whenever I tried to create , It raised a popup for the required field.

For the lookup, Let's assume Lookup name is Fruits, I select Fruits, It will redirect to Fruits lookup view.I will select Mango from the given lookup value.

Again I will go to same lookup and press over clear value button and come back to create followup workOrder view. All lookup value will be deleted.

Again I will select the same lookup Field, I will select someother fruits instead of Mango. I cannot select anyother value in the lookup. It is taking only Mango as a value to the lookup attribute.

I haven't apply any filter method to this lookup. Will it be create any issue.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you paste your Lookup validation code, or filter code if you have any?

Comment: By saying it's only "taking Mango", do you mean that the validation logic throws an error?  What is the actual symptom in the application when you select another fruit than Mango?  Is the lookup not closing?

Comment: no validation not seems to be the issue basically if I select something like mango then if i click on ok then lookup is closed and value is displayed as mango but if i again want to select anything rather than mango then the value is not updated & on close of look up i still see Mango only. Basically value doesnt get cleared.